# JQuery .text() Multi-Line

Tags: jquery

Is there a way I can turn this obnoxiously long line of text into a paragraph?

Before:

```
$('.ContText-1').text('For a business to thrive, it needs a team of people who are dedicated to its success. Paul Lister, Bryan Jeter, and Bryan Lloyd are committed to being a part of that team for each of their clients.');
```

After:

```
$('.ContText-1').text('
             For a business to thrive, it needs a team of people who are dedicated to its 
        success. Paul Lister, Bryan Jeter, and Bryan Lloyd are committed to being a part of 
        that team for each of their clients.
');
```

If I run the paragraph one I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`
Its referencing to the single quotation mark after the `(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're attempting to break the string in your code, not the output, you can use a template literal by delimiting the string with `` ` ``:

```
$('.ContText-1').text(`
  For a business to thrive, it needs a team of people who are dedicated to its 
  success. Paul Lister, Bryan Jeter, and Bryan Lloyd are committed to being a part of 
  that team for each of their clients.
`);
```

Note that this is completely unsupported in any version of IE, although works in every other modern browser - even Edge.

Alternatively you can append each line separately:

```
$('.ContText-1').text(
  'For a business to thrive, it needs a team of people who are dedicated to its ' + 
  'success. Paul Lister, Bryan Jeter, and Bryan Lloyd are committed to being a part of ' + 
  'that team for each of their clients.'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `text()` method use `html()` method and use `<br/>` to break the line

```
$('.ContText-1').html('<br/>For a business to thrive, it needs a team of people who are dedicated to its <br/>success. Paul Lister, Bryan Jeter, and Bryan Lloyd are committed to being a part of <br/> that team for each of their clients.');
```

Comment: The problem isnt the paragraph. The problem is in the code editor I have a long line of code that looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enclosing the String with ' , try to use ` .

At least in newer iteration of JS this should work fine.

UPDATE:

Actually, this had been covered before: [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: That doesnt work because I have single quotation markes in the string and `\` doesnt escape it with `